# Bind repeater contents vertically on UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have asp.net repeater(data control) and currently it looks on UI like this [image]

The id of the repeaters are row wise , I want to bind it vertically with same look , My current code for repeater is follows

```
<table><tr><td>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOptions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptOptions_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtLetter" runat="server" MaxLength="40" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" onkeydown="navigate(event);" BorderWidth="1px" Height="25px" Style="margin-left: 110px; display: inline; margin-top: 16px;" Visible="true" Width="200px" Enabled="false" oncopy="return(false);" oncut="return(false);" onpaste="return(false);" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="None" >
  </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: i am tryting to use in  </ItemTemplate> something like this but not working             <%# (((Container.ItemIndex) + 1) == 3 ? "</tr><td style='width:50%'></td>": "" )%>

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOptions" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table style="width: 50%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLetter" runat="server" MaxLength="40" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"
                    onkeydown="navigate(event);" BorderWidth="1px" Height="25px" Style="margin-left: 110px;
                    display: inline; margin-top: 16px;" Visible="true" Width="200px" Enabled="false"
                    oncopy="return(false);" oncut="return(false);" onpaste="return(false);" autocomplete="off"
                    AutoCompleteType="None">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </td> </tr> </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```